# Angularjs $http is unable to get data from Asp.net webapi 4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build an application with Asp.net web api and Angularjs

I am trying to get data from API but I am getting a null error as a result.

**Asp.net web api code**

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/user")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("login")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage login(string userId, string password)
        {
...code to fetch data
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
```

**web config**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );


    var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

    formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

**Angular Js Code**

```
        this.get = function (url, headers = {}) {

        /// creating a defer
        var def = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: '',
            headers: headers

        }).success(function (data) {
            def.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (error) {
            def.reject(error);
        });

        return def.promise;
    };
```

**Result**

When I am trying to `get` the result by hitting the API URl I am getting error `null`

If I am opening the url in web browser then it is returning the JSON

**Network Log**

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "WebInspector",
      "version": "537.36"
    },
    "pages": [],
    "entries": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2016-06-02T16:27:59.550Z",
        "time": 25.981999933719635,
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "http://localhost:62158/api/user/login?userId=undefined&password=abc",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "http://localhost:8000"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, sdch"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "localhost:62158"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6,und;q=0.4"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "http://localhost:8000/"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [
            {
              "name": "userId",
              "value": "undefined"
            },
            {
              "name": "password",
              "value": "abc"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": 429,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Thu, 02 Jun 2016 16:27:59 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Server",
              "value": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-AspNet-Version",
              "value": "4.0.30319"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Powered-By",
              "value": "ASP.NET"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-SourceFiles",
              "value": "=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNca2lyXERlc2t0b3BcRSBEcml2ZVxXb3JrIExpdmVcTml0aW4gS0sgU29mdHdhcmVcVmlkZW9MaWJyYXJ5XHByb2plY3RcVmlkZW9MSWJyYXJ5XFZpZGVvTElicmFyeVxhcGlcdXNlclxsb2dpbg==?="
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "46"
            },
            {
              "name": "Expires",
              "value": "-1"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 0,
            "mimeType": "application/json",
            "compression": 447,
            "text": ""
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 447,
          "bodySize": -447,
          "_transferSize": 0,
          "_error": ""
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 2.24999990314245,
          "dns": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0.19500008784235012,
          "wait": 22.8659999556839,
          "receive": 0.6709999870509336,
          "ssl": -1
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "[::1]",
        "connection": "15008"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Same Hit in browser giving result**

[image]

Comment: Use Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools or Fiddler to look at what's happening over HTTP, it will really help you figure it out.

Comment: Try passing an empty object instead of empty string.  `data: {}`  Btw, `$http` already returns a promise, there is no need to make another promise.

Comment: just an advice, $http already return a promise. You don't need to wrap it

Comment: I understand the `$http` returns a promise..My bad. But the point is why am I getting an error of value `null` when the status is 200OK also where is the data the API is returning. I am able to get the data in Postman and in simple http request in any web browser

Comment: Is the URL the exact same as the one that you posted?

Comment: @Katana24 yes its the same.

Comment: So its http://localhost:62158/api/user/login?userId=undefined&password=abc.json then correct?

Comment: I clicked on it and it gave me the default result that I am returning from the backend. Now you are scaring me... @Katana24

Comment: @VikasBansal of course it did - that's the url you posted and it will resolve that to your local :)

Comment: @Katana24 I regret but the problem persists. I think there is something wrong in ASP.net web api... perhaps, it is making the mess...

Answer (score 3):

As KKKKKKKK and rick have already pointed out you don't need to create another promise as `$http.get` will already return one. You should also make use of `then` as opposed to `succcess/failure`

So what you want should look like this:

```
function getData() {
  return $http.get('path-to-api/api.json').then( 
    function success(result) {
      // Do stuff with it
      return result.data;
    },
    function failure(err) {
      return err;
    });
}
```

Note this places the call in a service and returns the function in an object from that service.

**EDIT** 
Because the comments concates URLS I'll add this as an edit:
So the url you're hitting on the angular side is:
http://localhost:62158/api/user/login?userId=undefined&password=abc.json
or is http://localhost:62158/api/user/login?userId=undefined&password=abc

Comment: I'd also suggest sticking a breakpoint/debugger inside the functions returned above to see if it gets to that point and then inspect the objects to see if your data is actually there. If it isn't, and the response is ok, then you're probably not returning the data from the api

Comment: **errorr**
`{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost:62158/api/user/login?userId=undefined&password=asfd","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}`

**Response**
`Request URL:http://localhost:62158/api/user/login?userId=undefined&password=asdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:62158` **same hit in browser** print `{
code: "successfull",
message: "Valid User."
}`

Comment: I understand I can refactor the code. I apologize for my bad. However the question I posted here is about why $http is not able to get the data.

Comment: sir, Actaully,  for testing purpose i am always returning status 200OK and I clicked on both URLs that you provided in the EDIT and both are working fine and printing `{
code: "successfull",
message: "Valid User."
}`

Answer (score 0):

**@Katana24** I do not know how to thank you but you made me get this answer... thanks a lot.

**Reason**

Asp.net web api does not allow *cross origin* request until and unless you add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in `web.config` file. I made it `*` so from any origin the APIes is accessible.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Good job - it did seem like if you could hit the server but not see any data back then something must be wrong server side. Glad you found the solution. I accept cash ;) haha